# Removing duplicates in MS Access 2010 (like in Excel)

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, no-duplicates

I currently have some MS Access tables which are too large to be handled using Excel. I basically need to know how to remove duplicates based on one column, thus deleting lines and keeping everything else unchanged. Example:

This is an example of how my table is

a1  (...)   (...)   1   (...)   (...)

a1  (...)   (...)   2   (...)   (...)

a1  (...)   (...)   3   (...)   (...)

a1  (...)   (...)   4   (...)   (...)

a1  (...)   (...)   6   (...)   (...)

a1  (...)   (...)   7   (...)   (...)

b1  (...)   (...)   8   (...)   (...)

b1  (...)   (...)   9   (...)   (...)

b1  (...)   (...)   10  (...)   (...)

c1  (...)   (...)   11  (...)   (...)

c1  (...)   (...)   12  (...)   (...)

This is what I need:

a1  (...)   (...)   1   (...)   (...)

b1  (...)   (...)   8   (...)   (...)

c1  (...)   (...)   11  (...)   (...)

In excel I would just use the function remove duplicates and select the first column.

How can I do this in MS Access 2010?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just write an aggregate query and turn it into a make-table action query:

```
SELECT colLetter, Min(colNumber) As newColNumber
INTO newtable
FROM tableName
GROUP BY colLetter
```

Or use a DISTINCT clause with DLookUp or DMin:

```
SELECT DISTINCT colLetter,
DLookUp("colNumber", "tableName", "colLetter='" & tableName.colLetter & "'") As newColNumber
INTO newtable
FROM tableName
```

Altogether, unlike Excel, you have to understand the structure of your data in Access as records process together and do not operate independently like spreadsheet cells.